# how to reverse 'list' function to its original input

Tags: r

I `list` some data frames(same structures) to a list to perform `lapply` to each data frames. But after the lapply i want the list elements back to the original data frames format.

Is there any function except for loop to do this?

```
dt1<-data.frame(a=c(1,1,1),b=c(2,2,2))
dt2<-data.frame(a=c(3,3,3),b=c(4,4,4))
dt3<-data.frame(a=c(5,5,5),b=c(6,6,6))
lst<-list(dt1,dt2,dt3)
for (i in 1:3)
{ #after the data manipilaton 
assign(paste('newdt',i,sep=''),lst[[i]])
}
> dt1
  a b
1 1 2
2 1 2
3 1 2
> dt2
  a b
1 3 4
2 3 4
3 3 4
> dt3
  a b
1 5 6
2 5 6
3 5 6
```

desired output (I did not include the data manipulation part so the output and input looks the same)

```
> newdt1
  a b
1 1 2
2 1 2
3 1 2
> newdt2
  a b
1 3 4
2 3 4
3 3 4
> newdt3
  a b
1 5 6
2 5 6
3 5 6
```

Comment: It is better to keep the datasets in a `list` rather than creating new objects in the global environment

Comment: ...I agree with what @akrun said. But technically speaking, `list2env` will do what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sapply, manipulate on each data frame in the loop, return it as a list. rename the list to newdt-n and you should be good to go.

```
A <- sapply(1:length(lst), function(i){
        a_tmp <- list(lst[[i]])
        names(a_tmp) <- sprintf('newdt%s', i)
        a_tmp
    })

> names(A)
[1] "newdt1" "newdt2" "newdt3"

> class(A)
[1] "list"


> A
$newdt1
  a b
1 1 2
2 1 2
3 1 2

$newdt2
  a b
1 3 4
2 3 4
3 3 4

$newdt3
  a b
1 5 6
2 5 6
3 5 6
```

For brevity sake...here's with some meaningless manip:

```
> A <- sapply(1:length(lst), function(i){
+     new_col <- lst[[i]] %>% mutate(sum_ab = a + b)
+     a_tmp <- list(new_col)
+     names(a_tmp) <- sprintf('newdt%s', i)
+     a_tmp
+ })
> A
$newdt1
  a b sum_ab
1 1 2      3
2 1 2      3
3 1 2      3

$newdt2
  a b sum_ab
1 3 4      7
2 3 4      7
3 3 4      7

$newdt3
  a b sum_ab
1 5 6     11
2 5 6     11
3 5 6     11
```